# VB.Net help selecting first index of string with regex

Tags: regex, vb.net, textbox

I was wondering if there was a way I could start a selection from the Regex string i have in the below example

The below example works exactly how I want it too however if there is text that matches before it on another line it is choosing the wrong text and highlighting it.

What im wondering is if there is a way to get the start index of the regex string?

```
If Regex.IsMatch(Me.TextBox1.Text, "\b" + Regex.Escape("is") + "\b") Then
    Me.TextBox1.SelectionStart = Me.TextBox1.Text.IndexOf("is")
    Dim linenumber As Integer = Me.TextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(Me.TextBox1.Text.IndexOf("is"))
    Me.TextBox1.SelectionLength = Me.TextBox1.Lines(linenumber).Length
    Me.TextBox1.Focus()
    Me.TextBox1.SelectedText = "is " & Me.TextBox2.Text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [System.Text.RegularExpression.Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) object has a property which should help you here: [Match.Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  `Match.Index` will tell you where the capture starts, and [Match.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.length%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) tells you how long it is.  Using those you could change your code to look like this:

```
If Regex.IsMatch(Me.TextBox1.Text, "\b" + Regex.Escape("is") + "\b") Then
    Dim m as Match
    m = Regex.Match(Me.TextBox1.Text, "\b" + Regex.Escape("is") + "\b")
    Me.TextBox1.SelectionStart = m.Index
    Dim linenumber As Integer = Me.TextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(m.Index)
    Me.TextBox1.SelectionLength = Me.TextBox1.Lines(linenumber).Length
    Me.TextBox1.Focus()
    Me.TextBox1.SelectedText = "is " & Me.TextBox2.Text
```

Comment: with your example i tried this and I am getting the following error
Reference to a non-shared member requires an object with the Regex.Match

Comment: Okay, this is because my brain compiler is running out of juice.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  The exception was because `Regex.Match()` is the static equivalent of compiling a `Regex` object and calling its instanced `Match` method, yet the overload for the static version of `Match()` requires you to provide the pattern as well as the string to be searched.

Comment: ah, I did remember looking somewhere and seeing that, thanks so much for the help. works like a charm